# How to avoid Getting ORACLE Mutating trigger error

Tags: oracle

I created the trigger to update the oracle data base table after insert.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Update_ACU     
  AFTER INSERT ON TBL_ACU      
  FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN       
  UPDATE TBL_ACU     
  SET    CURRENCY = 'XXX'    
  WHERE  ACCOUNT like '%1568';   
END ;


I inserted record as

insert into TBL_ACU values('23','USD','1231568');
```

I am getting table ORACLE Mutating trigger error.

Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: So after inserting any row, you want all rows that have an account ending with 1568 to have their currency set to 'XXX'? That's a real requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot modify the table from the trigger if the trigger is called upon modification of that table. There are various solutions to this problem including an `AFTER STATEMENT` trigger and caching modifications in some collection defined in PL/SQL PACKAGE, howewer in your situation I'd rather change the body of your trigger to this:

```
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.ACCOUNT LIKE '%1568' THEN
      :NEW.CURRENCY := 'XXX';
  END IF;
END;
```

You can use the `:NEW` and `:OLD` variables inside the trigger, which identify the *new* and *old* values of the record accordingly. Modifying values of the `:NEW` record will cause changes in data actually inserted to the database.

Comment: You have missed a `:` while assigning a new value for currency.

Comment: @Dba Too much java will kill you, they say ;) Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to do this.

Try like this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER update_acu
     BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_acu
     FOR EACH ROW
     WHEN (NEW.ACCOUNT LIKE '%1568')
BEGIN
     :NEW.currency := 'XXX';
END ;
```

Comment: is it right WHEN (NEW.ACCOUNT LIKE '%1568')
i think you missed ':' before NEW.

WHEN (:NEW.ACCOUNT LIKE '%1568')
Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yeah sure, before insertion it'll check this.

Comment: Refer this link for better understanding. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm